# How can I change the default home page url in an Android custom ROM?

Tags: android, rom, custom-rom

Hello I'm working in a custom ROM for Android. I would like to change the default home page url of the browsers like Chrome. Is there any file to change this?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter if the ROM is custom or not. You need to modify the chrome/firefox apk to archieve this.